# python dict of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have following dict:

```
items_temp = dict(fruits=["apple", "orange"], vegetables=["carrot", "potato"], animals=["dog", "cat"])
```

and following list to be verified what kind of things it contains.

```
check = ["orange", "dog", "apple"]
```

is there any clever pythonic way to obtain following dict from data above?:

```
output = dict(fruits = ["orange", "apple"], animals=["dog"])
```

Comment: This operation would be more efficient if your dict went from `"apple"` to `"fruit"` instead of `"fruits"` to `["apple", "orange"]`.

Comment: what output would you want when `check = ["orange", "dog"]`? Would you want `fruts` in your result to be `["orange"]` or `["orange", "apple"]`?

Comment: @Hamms based on `animals` (which contains `"cat"`), just `["orange"]`.

Comment: that's what I get for not scrolling the example dict all the way to the right :P

Comment: @user2357112 and sorting a list of strings would be easier if they were already alphabetical.  Your point is?

Comment: @RoadieRich: It's likely that the questioner has control over the format of the dict, or that the questioner can convert the dict once and then use the more efficient representation to perform this operation repeatedly.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't think it's safe to assume the questioner has control over the input, unless they explicitly state so. I'd consider it far more likely that the data is provided externally - whether it's from an examiner or an external service.  And in this case, doing the transformation would take just as much effort as actually solving the problem as written.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to do the following:

```
check = set(['orange', 'dog', 'apple'])
output = {k: check.intersection(v) for k, v in items_temp.items() if check.intersection(v)}
```

Basically, I'm checking the intersection between `check` and the values of your dictionary.  If there *is* an intersection, we add it to the output.

This will give you a dictionary with sets as values, but you can convert that pretty easily.

---

Note that we're doing the intersection check twice.  That's a bit annoying (and we definitely don't need to) if we add an extra step into the processing pipeline...

```
check = set(['orange', 'dog', 'apple'])
keys_intersect = ((k, check.intersection(v)) for k, v in items_temp.iteritems())
output = {k: intersect for k, intersect in keys_intersect if intersect}
```

Comment: It actually adds `v` to the output, not the intersection. And you should assume Python 3, which doesn't have `iteritems`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a clean, single step way to get what you want, but you can do it in two:

```
>>> output = {k:[v for v in vs if v in check] for k,vs in items_temp.items()}
>>> output
{'vegetables': [], 'animals': ['dog'], 'fruits': ['apple', 'orange']}
```

Next, we just need to filter out the empty lists:

```
>>> output = {k:vs for k,vs in output.items() if vs}
>>> output
{'animals': ['dog'], 'fruits': ['apple', 'orange']}
```

If you've got a lot of items to check, you can speed things up considerably by turning `check` into a `set`, but *premature optimization is the root of all evil*.

Edit: I suppose you can do it in one:

```
>>> output = {k:[v for v in vs if v in check] for k,vs in items_temp.items() if any(v in check for v in vs)}
>>> output
{'animals': ['dog'], 'fruits': ['apple', 'orange']}
```

But that's over-complicating things with redundant testing.

You could also do

```
{k:vs for k,vs in ((k,[v for v in vs if v in check]) for k,vs in items_temp.items()) if vs}
```

To do it in one step without redundant membership checking, but now we're getting a little silly.

Answer (score -4):

Why don't you use a dictionary?

```
a={"Mobin":"Iranian","Harry":"American"}
```

and you can get that with this:

```
print a.get("Mobin")
```

when you run this code,you can see 'Iranian' in screen